# How can I restart a windows service programmatically in .NET

Tags: c#, windows-services

How can I restart a windows service programmatically in .NET? 
Also, I need to do an operation when the service restart is completed.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Take a look at the [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller) class.

To perform the operation that needs to be done when the service is restarted, I guess you should do that in the Service yourself (if it is your own service).
If you do not have access to the source of the service, then perhaps you can use the `WaitForStatus` method of the `ServiceController`.

Comment: Does this work within the service itself? Can a windows service restart itself programmatically ?

Answer (score 84):

[This article](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/) uses the [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class to write methods for Starting, Stopping, and Restarting Windows services; it might be worth taking a look at.

Snippet from the article (the "Restart Service" method):

```
public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

    // count the rest of the timeout
    int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
    timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2-millisec1));

    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution, is that in my case this operation needed admin privilege. And I can't change (specify) user during runtime.

Comment: @Slavik if admin privs are needed, then it wouldn't matter what approach you would take programmatically; you'd likely need to even use an Admin-level console to use the command-line tools, and if you tried via the Task Manager, you would likely get Access Denied.

Answer (score 28):

#### An example using by ServiceController Class

```
private void RestartWindowsService(string serviceName)
{
    ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    try
    {
        if ((serviceController.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) || (serviceController.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)))
        {
            serviceController.Stop();
        }
        serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
        serviceController.Start();
        serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
    }
    catch
    {
        ShowMsg(AppTexts.Information, AppTexts.SystematicError, MessageBox.Icon.WARNING);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You could also call the `net` command to do this. Example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "stop IISAdmin");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "start IISAdmin");
```

Comment: I like this answer because it needs no additional references or helper classes. You might want to add a .WaitForExit(); to make sure the service has been stopped before you start it again:

    `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "stop IISAdmin").WaitForExit();`
    `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "start IISAdmin").WaitForExit();`

Answer (score 16):

This answer is based on @Donut Answer (the most up-voted answer of this question), but with some modifications.

1. Disposing of `ServiceController` class after each use, because it implements `IDisposable` interface.
2. Reduce the parameters of the method: there is no need to the `serviceName` parameter being passed for each method, we can set it in the constructor, and each other method will use that service name. 
   This is also more OOP-friendly.
3. Handle the catch exception in a way that this class could be used as a component.
4. Remove the `timeoutMilliseconds` parameter from each method.
5. Add two new methods `StartOrRestart` and `StopServiceIfRunning`, which could be considered as a wrapper for other basic methods, The purpose of those methods are only to avoid exceptions, as described in the comment.

Here is the class

```
public class WindowsServiceController
{
    private readonly string serviceName;

    public WindowsServiceController(string serviceName)
    {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    // this method will throw an exception if the service is NOT in Running status.
    public void RestartService()
    {
        using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
        {
            try
            {
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);

                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Can not restart the Windows Service {serviceName}", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    // this method will throw an exception if the service is NOT in Running status.
    public void StopService()
    {
        using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
        {
            try
            {
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Can not Stop the Windows Service [{serviceName}]", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    // this method will throw an exception if the service is NOT in Stopped status.
    public void StartService()
    {
        using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
        {
            try
            {
                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Can not Start the Windows Service [{serviceName}]", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    // if service running then restart the service if the service is stopped then start it.
    // this method will not throw an exception.
    public void StartOrRestart()
    {
        if (IsRunningStatus)
            RestartService();
        else if (IsStoppedStatus)
            StartService();
    }

    // stop the service if it is running. if it is already stopped then do nothing.
    // this method will not throw an exception if the service is in Stopped status.
    public void StopServiceIfRunning()
    {
        using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsRunningStatus)
                    return;

                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Can not Stop the Windows Service [{serviceName}]", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsRunningStatus => Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;

    public bool IsStoppedStatus => Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped;

    public ServiceControllerStatus Status
    {
        get
        {
            using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
            {
                return service.Status;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**If you are using .NET Core you have to download [System.ServiceProcess package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController) 

And this will work only on WINDOWS**

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
var theController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("IISAdmin");

theController.Stop();
theController.Start();
```

Don't forget to add the System.ServiceProcess.dll to your project for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Svc_Controller_in_C_Sharp.aspx).

Here is a snippet from the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Svc_Controller_in_C_Sharp.aspx).

```
//[QUICK CODE] FOR THE IMPATIENT
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
// ADD "using System.ServiceProcess;" after you add the 
// Reference to the System.ServiceProcess in the solution Explorer
using System.ServiceProcess;
namespace Using_ServiceController{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            ServiceController myService = new ServiceController();
            myService.ServiceName = "ImapiService";
            string svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
                if (svcStatus == "Running"){
                    myService.Stop();
                }else if(svcStatus == "Stopped"){
                    myService.Start();
                }else{
                    myService.Stop();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point in calling ToString() on enum and then comparing strings instead of enums?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a service to restart after failure. So a restart can be forced by throwing an exception.

Use recovery tab on service properties.

Be sure to use reset fail count property to prevent service stopping altogether.

Comment: This was my last option, but I didn't find other way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I needed somethin more complex, because sometimes services with depencies couldnt be restarted and just throw exception or service could be set to "disabled" and so on.

So this is what i did:

(It checks if service does exist, if its "Disabled" it will set service to "Auto" and when it couldnt restart service it will use taskkill command to kill service through PID and then start it again (You need to be carefull with dependent services with this cause you will need to start/restart them too).

And it just returns true/false if restart was sucessfull

Tested on WIN10 only.

PS: working on version which detect dependent services when using taskkill and restart them too

```
//Get windows service status
    public static string GetServiceStatus(string NameOfService)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(NameOfService);

        switch (sc.Status)
        {
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                return "Running";
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
                return "Stopped";
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
                return "Paused";
            case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
                return "Stopping";
            case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
                return "Starting";
            default:
                return "Status Changing";
        }
    }

    //finds if service exists in OS
    public static bool DoesServiceExist(string serviceName)
    {
        return ServiceController.GetServices().Any(serviceController => serviceController.ServiceName.Equals(serviceName));
    }

    //finds startup type of service
    public static string GetStartupType(string serviceName)
    {
        ManagementObject objManage = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='"+serviceName+"'");
        objManage.Get();

        string status1 = objManage["StartMode"].ToString();

        return status1;
    }

    //restart service through PID
    public static bool RestartServiceByPID(string NameOfService)
    {
        LogWriter log = new LogWriter("TaskKilling: " + NameOfService);

        string strCmdText = "/C taskkill /f /fi \"SERVICES eq " + NameOfService + "\"";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);

        using(ServiceController ScvController = new ServiceController(NameOfService))
        {
            ScvController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);

            if (GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Stopped")
            {
                ScvController.Start();
                ScvController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

                if (GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Running")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Restart windows service
    public static bool RestartWindowsService(string NameOfService)
    {

        try
        {
            //check if service exists
            if(DoesServiceExist(NameOfService) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Service " + NameOfService + " was not found.");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //if it does it check startup type and if it is disabled it will set it to "Auto"
                if (GetStartupType(NameOfService) == "Disabled")
                {
                    using (var svc = new ServiceController(NameOfService))
                    {
                        ServiceHelper.ChangeStartMode(svc, ServiceStartMode.Automatic);

                        if (svc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                        {
                            svc.Start();
                            svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

                            if(GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Running")
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            svc.Stop();
                            svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);

                            if(GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Stopped")
                            {
                                svc.Start();
                                svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

                                if(GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Running")
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                            //restart through PID
                            else
                            {
                                return RestartServiceByPID(NameOfService);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                //If service is not disabled it will restart it
                else
                {
                    using(ServiceController ScvController = new ServiceController(NameOfService))
                    {
                        if(GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Running")
                        {

                            ScvController.Stop();
                            ScvController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);

                            if(GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Stopped")
                            {
                                ScvController.Start();
                                ScvController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

                                if(GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Running")
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }

                            }
                            //if stopping service fails, it uses taskkill
                            else
                            {
                                return RestartServiceByPID(NameOfService);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ScvController.Start();
                            ScvController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

                            if(GetServiceStatus(NameOfService) == "Running")
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return RestartServiceByPID(NameOfService);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Call `Environment.Exit` with an error code greater than 0, which seems appropriate, then on install we configure the service to restart on error.

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

I have done same thing in my Service. It is working fine.

Comment: What about the operation when the service restart?

Comment: It behave to be normal fresh start.