# How can i access machine on same network and start a service?

Tags: c#, .net

I have winforms application which accesses WCF service on some Windows machine on same network. Sometimes WCF service is down due to some error in it, i want to be able to access machine with service and start the service up if it's down.

I want to do that from WinForms C# application.

How do i access Windows machine from WinForms application and execute command on it. ie

sc \machine stop

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187836/how-do-i-restart-a-service-on-a-remote-machine-in-windows

Comment: @DanielA.White, I want to access via C#.

Comment: please explain what you have tried and also make it more of a programming question.

Comment: Looks like a dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454502/how-can-i-restart-a-windows-service-programatically-in-net

Answer (score 2):

Try the [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssbk2tf3.aspx) class.

```
var svc = new ServiceController("WCFServiceName", "ComputerName");
if (svc.Status == ControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
  sc.Start();
}
```