# Unable to start and stop service using ServiceController

Tags: c#, service, class-library, servicecontroller

I have the below methods to start and stop a service. I call this method from another Console application to debug since I've used the methods in a Class Library(DLL).

The application is started with administrative rights.

```
public void ServiceStart()
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController();
    service.ServiceName = "ASP.NET State Service";
    service.Start();
}

public void ServiceStop()
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController();
    service.ServiceName = "ASP.NET State Service";
    service.Stop();
}
```

But when I call `Start()` or `Stop()` an exception with the following message is thrown:

> Cannot open ASP.NET State Service service on computer '.'

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you running the program with administrative rights?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I restart a windows service programatically in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454502/how-can-i-restart-a-windows-service-programatically-in-net)

Comment: Check out the Windows EventLog

Comment: Works for me.  Its clearly not seeing the service on your computer

Comment: See the answer below - and my comment - you have choices if its  not working to try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass the **Service name**, not the **Display name**.
Always check the service properties in the "Services" application.

Try again with

```
service.ServiceName = "aspnet_state";
```

Alternatively, you can create the ServiceController instance using the display name:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("ASP.NET State Service");
```

since the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3ket56y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the constructor argument says:

> The name that identifies the service to the system. This can also be
>   the display name for the service.

Also note that a call to

```
service.Start();
```

returns immediately, without waiting for the service to start.
You should call

```
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
```

if you want to make sure the service is running before your application continues.

Comment: I used `ServiceController x = new ServiceController("ASP.NET State Service");` which worked fine on my PC - so it doesnt suggest thats it

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, since the documentation *for the constructor* says that "This can also be the display name for the service." However, for the ServiceName property that is **not** the case.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  But its worth noting the OP has the choice of doing that.

Comment: @BugFinder I added that to my answer. I like to use the service name rather than the display name since they are generally shorter and simpler.

Comment: Oh, dont disagree, but not everyone seems to know how to get the short name - although its not hard.

Comment: Done. Add also gave a +1 for the edited part which i really had to use.

Answer (score 2):

Open Visual studio as Administrator