# Restart and monitor service from Website in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, windows-services

I have a console application that monitors a folder for imports and parses them.  I want to convert this to a Windows Service.  What I'm not sure how to do or if it's possible is have an IIS hosted website be able to show the status of that service and manually restart it if necessary. The website and the windows service would be running on the same server.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Or if a website can even control a service.  At a basic level, can a website monitor and restart a service if necessary.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's exactly what I needed, and it even has a .Net Core version.  If you put that as the answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a website that checks for the status and restarts the Windows Service by using the [`ServiceController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454523/2141621) (or even the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7)) for sample code on both checking the status and restarting the service.

Just keep in mind that the website will have to run (under IIS settings) with a user identity that has enough privileges (normally administrator) on the server.